# ¿Cómo seteo el mismo estilo CSS para los links de dos elementos (2 id)?

Tags: css

quiero darle el mismo estilo a 2 links particulares y mi código actual es el siguiente:

```
a#id1:link {color:darkgray;}
a#id1:hover {color:white;}
a#id1:active {color:red;}
a#id1:visited {color:black;}

a#id2:link {color:darkgray;}
a#id2:hover {color:white;}
a#id2:active {color:red;}
a#id2:visited {color:black;}
```

¿Como puedo ponerlo resumido? Intente con algo como a#id1#id2:link {color:darkgray;} pero no funciona.

Saludos, Leandro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo los agrupas con una coma como separador indicando que la misma regla es aplicada a los dos selectores así:

```css
a#id1:link,a#id2:link{color:darkgray;}
a#id1:hover,a#id2:hover {color:white;}
a#id1:active, a#id2:active {color:red;}
a#id1:visited, a#id2:visited {color:black;}
```

```html
<a id="id1">Link1</a><a id="id2">Link2</a>
```

**Agregando la solución de @alanfcm:**

Como decía **alanfcm**  en el comentario también puedes agregar una clase en común para los dos así:

```css
a.link:link{color:darkgray;}
a.link:hover{color:white;}
a.link:active{color:red;}
a.link:visited{color:black;}
```

```html
<a id="id1" class="link">Link1</a><a id="id2" class="link">Link2</a>
```

Comment: Tambien podrias agregar una clase a los dos.

Comment: Muchas gracias gente! había probado con comas, pero de la forma incorrecta! ahora anduvo bárbaro! gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tambien crear una clase para ambos links:

```
<a href="#" id="id1" class="gris"><a href="#" id="id2" class="gris">
```

y el css seria:

```
.gris{ color:darkgray;}
```